# Importing data via Excel

Tags: excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am using [this procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960729) to import Vendors into the `VendTable` table. It works fine, but sometimes, I need to delete all the vendors I've just created and tweak the data and then would like to try again.

But it seems once an `Definition Group` has been used to import data, it can't import any more again.

I get: "No data imported" in the InfoLog.

The only way I can do this is by recreating a new `Definition Group` via the `Template Wizard` which, well, I don't want to.

Any ideas to be able to reuse a `Definition Group`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reset the `Definition` Group status doing: Select the `Definition Group`, click `Table Setup` button to the right, in the `Import Status` column, select `Import`. Save. Run the import again.